# Unable to load bootstrap navigation bar in django (maybe obvious solution)

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-4

My navigation bar on my home page does not click, open and dsiplay links. I understand that I need to pull the javascript code to do this. Here is picture. Those three lines cannot be clicked and opened.
[image]

This is what should happen when those three lines are clicked. 
[image]

I've gone through all the questions in stackoverflow, but still cannot get it to load. I've tried to upload the bootstrap CDN, save javascript and load it via static files, tried different javascript files and it does not get the navbar to work. I maybe uploading the wrong files. The CSS files do load, so some static files do load.

Here is the html file.

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Album example for Bootstrap</title>
     <link  href="{% static 'css/album.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link  href="{% static 'css/album.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins)-->
<script href="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}" ></script>  <!--jquery-->

<!-- <script href = "{% static 'js/collapse.js' %}"></script>

<script href = "{% static 'js/dropdown.js' %}"></script> -->

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="collapse bg-inverse" id="navbarHeader">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-8 py-4">
            <h4 class="text-white">
            <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
          </h4>
            <p class="text-muted">About us.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4 py-4">
            <h4 class="text-white">Contact</h4>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="text-white">Contact us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Like on Facebook</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="text-white">Follow on Twitter</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
      <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">MedTrend</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my settings file related to this.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "static",),
)
```

Comment: Where's your `static` folder located?

Comment: This is all under a catalog app. It's in that folder. I then have a css, js, and img folder and each individual file in their respective folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you're using `Django 2.0` and your static settings are **working** then you need to use **`{% load static %}`** instead of **`{% load staticfiles %}`**
- If you need a reference then here's a working example for static files:

**`project/settings.py`**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Up here, I have a folder in my project root called 'static' which contains folder like 'css', 'js' etc. You also need to set this up in your urls.py so it can be accessible to the template. So I would do it like this:

**`project/urls.py`**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static        #---imports
from django.conf import settings                  #---imports

urlpatterns = [

    path('', user_login),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), 
] 

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()       # <------- Add this
```

Then at the top of your HTML page, import the static files

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}          #<-----this

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}">
```

---

> ### Update

You forgot to add `bootstrap.bundle.js` in **your static/js** and then in your `base_generic.html` add below:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/b.b.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This still does not work for me. The sheet loads like normal. however, I cannot press the three lines in the navbar and get them to open to reveal the about, contact, etc.

Comment: If you're on production i.e `Debug= False`, you need to run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: I'm not on production, Debug = True. Added some pictures, hope they help with clarity. Everything else loads fine, so I don't think it's a problem with my static files.

Comment: Then add the required code so that i can reenact the problem and have a go then.

Comment: I did add your code, but the problem remains the same. My static files are loading. I can send you my code if you want to take a look.

Comment: Have you uploaded it to some git repo or anywhere from i can take a look?

Comment: I added you to collaborators to the project, so you should get an invite and be able to view it. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help. I'm spent 5 years on R and in data science, so if there's anything you need with those two, please reach out. I'm just learning django and reviewing my python from college.

Comment: Sure @JR. I received the invitation and cloning it as we speak. will definitely get back to you for data science. Okay, i'll take a look and let you know the problem.

Comment: @JR lets connect over some messaging platform as we need to discuss a few things.

Comment: @anshuman Thank you for looking at it. Sent you a message on your website.